# Azure webjobs JobHostConfiguration missing and can't figure out to do the settings now

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-webjobssdk

I want to rewrite my current webjobs config to the version 3.0 but I can't get it to work with the documentation because I have no idea how to set the `dashboardconnectionstring` or `storageconnectionstring` without a config file.

```cs
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration
{
    NameResolver = new WebJobsNameResolver()
};

string defaultStorageConnectionString = string.Format( "Some dynamically generation string" );
config.DashboardConnectionString = defaultStorageConnectionString;
config.StorageConnectionString = defaultStorageConnectionString;

using(JobHost host = new JobHost(config))
{
    // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

I want to make it run continuously with the correct storage and dashboard connection string, without using a config file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 3.0.0 NuGet package update (non-beta) brought breaking changes. It's based on the generic host which is similar to the asp.net host. You could refer to the steps as below:

1.Add this line of code in your program.cs.

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) => {
    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
})
```

The whole code in Program.cs.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebJob1template
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .UseEnvironment("Development")
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) => {
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                })
                .ConfigureWebJobs(
                b =>
                {
                    b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices()
                    .AddAzureStorage()
                    .AddTimers()
                    .AddFiles();
                    //.AddDashboardLogging();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
                {
                    b.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                    b.AddConsole();
                })
                .UseConsoleLifetime();


            var host = builder.Build();

            using (host)
            {
                host.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2.Set `appsettings.json`(note that set it's property `Copy to Output Directory` or  `Copy always`):

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "xxxx",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "xxxx"
  }
}
```

3.Functions.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebJob1template
{
    public class Functions
    {        
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, ILogger log)
        {
            //log.WriteLine(message);
            log.LogInformation(message);
        }
    }
}
```

4.The output:
[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started).

**Update**:

As Joey said, we could use

```
config.AddInMemoryCollection(settings);
```

with

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> settings = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"ConnectionStrings:AzureWebJobsDashboard:0", "xxxxxxx"},
    {"ConnectionStrings:AzureWebJobsStorage:1", "xxxxxx"},
};
```

So that it will not use the config file. Here is the article about how to use [`AddInMemoryCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#bind-an-array-to-a-class)

Comment: I didn't want to use the appsettings.json for different reasons but i have found a solution.

By instead of using AddJsonFile i used AddInMemoryCollection( settings ) and settings is just a dictionary with the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Joey Cai's answer, there is a possibility to NOT use the JSON config file:

We had:

```
var storageAcc = "<< your connection string >>"
var jobHostConfig = new JobHostConfiguration(storageAcc);
var host = new JobHost(jobHostConfig);
host.RunAndBlock();
```

Now:

```
var storageAcc = "<< your connection string >>"
var settings = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"AzureWebJobsDashboard", storageAcc},
    {"AzureWebJobsStorage", storageAcc},
};

var builder = new HostBuilder();
builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
{
    config.AddInMemoryCollection(settings);
});

builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
{
    b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
});

var host = builder.Build();

using (host)
{
    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

<irony> Yay. What a nice looking code BTW. </irony>

The main difference between my version and version Joey posted as an update to his answer is that my dictionary had to include the key

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage"
```

instead of

```
"ConnectionStrings:AzureWebJobsStorage:0"
```

to stop from complaining. This way we were able to use the same config management as before.